# Remove tag from item Ttk Treeview

Tags: python, select, tags, treeview

I want to have different background for selected item in my Ttk Treeview, I have this.

```
self.tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", self.TableItemClick)

def TableItemClick(self, event):
    self.tree.item(self.tree.selection(), tags="selected")
```

But i how can i remove tags from items? Right now all stays with this tag.
I would need to remove this tag from all items and set it for the new one.
Thanks

**Edit**
I solved it with storing the previous item into variable and then giving it unselected tag

```
def TableItemClick(self, event):
    self.tree.item(self.selected, tags="unselected")
    self.tree.item(self.tree.selection(), tags="selected")
    self.selected = self.tree.selection()
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a window and a treeview

```
app = Tk()
tree = ttk.Treeview(app)
tree.pack()
```

Put some items into the treeview

```
tree.insert('', 'end', 'toplevel', text='title')
tree.insert('toplevel', 'end', text='some text', tags='tagred')
item_id = tree.insert('toplevel', 'end', text='some text', tags='tagyellow')
```

Configure items which have tag `'tagred'` to have red backgrounds

```
tree.tag_configure('tagred', background="red")
```

Configure items which have tag `'tagyellow'` to have yellow backgrounds

```
tree.tag_configure('tagyellow', background="yellow")
```

Use the id `item_id` we stored above to remove all tags from that item.

```
tree.item(item_id, tags=())
```

Start the app.

```
app.mainloop()
```

You'll notice that there is a yellow item but the item under it in the tree view isn't red.

Comment: Could you explain your code please? That way, it'll help others understand how it works.

Comment: Sure, added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution (in case your application allows for multiple items to be selected at once) could be to use the `.tag_has` method to have the 'TableItemClick' event handler first look for all items with the 'selected' tag. Then remove the tag from those, and apply the tag to only what is currently selected. With this method, you also wouldn't need to store the previous selection or use an extra 'unselected' tag.

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview()
self.tree.tag_configure( 'selected', background='red' )

def TableItemClick( self, event ):
    # Remove existing selected tags
    for iid in fileTree.tag_has( 'selected' ):
        self.tree.item( iid, tags=() )

    # Add selected tag to current selection
    for iid in self.tree.selection():
        self.tree.item( iid, tags='selected' )
```

However, this and other solutions here so far still have another potential problem in that they will remove other existing tags. So if your application uses other tags as well, you'll have to take the above code a step further. What I've done is just have a new widget class that inherits from ttk.Treeview, and then add these methods for non-destructively adding or removing tags:

```
    def addTag( self, iid, tagToAdd ):

        """ Adds the given tag from the given item, while preserving other tags it may have. """
        
        targetFileTags = self.item( iid, 'tags' ) # Returns a tuple
        targetFileTags = list( targetFileTags )
        targetFileTags.append( tagToAdd )

        self.item( iid, tags=targetFileTags )

    def removeTag( self, iid, tagToRemove ):

        """ Removes the given tag from the given item, while preserving other tags it may have. """

        currentTags = list( self.item( iid, 'tags' ) )
        if tagToRemove in currentTags:
            currentTags.remove( tagToRemove )
            self.item( iid, tags=currentTags )
```